# How to hide the menu bar under the editor window in PyCharm

Tags: user-interface, pycharm, editor, breadcrumbs, menubar

I'm not sure what's it called, but there is a bar window underneath the editor window, above the Debug/Terminal/Console windows, which shows on what indent / frame / layer you are currently at (with the cursor).

It's pretty redundant to me and catching up a full wide-screen line for me..

[image]

See that line:

```
Level1 > Level2() > Level3() > for Level4 in range(5)
```

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The breadcrumbs in the editor can be enabled or disabled, per language, checking the box at `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `General` `>` `Breadcrumbs` `>` `Show breadcrumbs`.

Placing the breadcrumbs at the top or bottom of the editor can be adjusted on the same page choosing `Placement` option with `Top` or `Bottom`.

This is shown in the below screenshot, see also the PyCharm documentation [Breadcrumbs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Settings_Editor_Breadcrumbs.html)

[image]